# A Round Britain Quiz Question

Tags: knowledge, connections-puzzle

*This style of question commemorates the [Round Britain Quiz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_Britain_Quiz) on BBC Radio 4: the format is one, long, cryptic question which has six parts to it, indicated by the letters a-f. Please submit answers explaining all parts as well as the connecting theme.*

Gosset's pseudonymous distribution (a), an encoding complementary to SAW (b), an audible encoding of 309 (c), a term associated with flux and high-tech cars (d), a unique alignment identifier (e) and erolocirt (f) are all literally related. How is this?

UPDATE: A friend with a better knowledge of biochemistry than I have tells me that I have erred in (c). Please apply a little poetic licence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well,

(a)

> Gosset was a statistician who worked for the Guinness company and was required by them to publish pseudonymously; he called himself "Student", and the distribution is surely **Student's t-distribution**.

(b)

> In flag semaphore, the letters S, A, W, and **T** between them use all of the eight possible flag positions exactly once each.

(c)

> the amino acid three-oh-nine -- excuse me, I mean **threonine** -- has single-letter abbreviation T. (But the "nine" at the end is actually pronounced like "knee" + -n.)

(d)

> This must be **Tesla**, a unit of magnetic flux and a brand of electric car; its standard abbreviation is T.

(e)

> For [extradiegetic](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64593438#64593438) [reasons](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64593442#64593442) I am pretty sure this must pertain to a Dungeons & Dragons alignment, but I have been unable to find any that is denoted "T". But! The ingenious @Stiv suggests in comments that the idea is: "True Neutral" (which is typically abbreviated to N, not T) is the only alignment that includes the word **True**, and conversely "True" is the only word that appears in exactly one alignment name. ("Lawful", "Chaotic", "Good", and "Evil" appear three times each. "Neutral" appears five times.) And of course "true" is commonly (e.g., in truth tables) abbreviated to T.

(f)

> Well, "erolocirt" is "tricolore" backwards. The Tricolore is the French flag, consisting of vertical bands in blue, white, and red, in that order, or the Italian flag, similar but green-white-red. A red-white-blue flag is the international maritime signal flag denoting **the letter T**.

These are all literally related

> with "literal" in the sense of "pertaining to a letter or letters": these all concern the letter T.

I am rather impressed by

> how soon after those comments in TSL Daniel managed to produce a puzzle combining the requisite ingredients.

Comment: I would like to mention that I figured out (c) _before_ seeing the edit, by the way :-).

Comment: Rot13(Gur jbeq 'Gehr' vf gur bayl jbeq gb nccrne va bayl bar bs gur Q&Q nyvtazragf (GEHR arhgeny) - nyy bgure jbeqf nccrne va gjb be zber. Gehr=G.)

Comment: Ooooh, nice catch @Stiv. That must be it!

Comment: For part e), I offer [this evidence](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=tn+true+neutral&client=safari&sca_esv=574510585&source=hp&ei=OUAwZbOqJtqukdUPj4Oo4AM&iflsig=AO6bgOgAAAAAZTBOSZrLcdqc_cShEt3wFYD8HASTgb_e&ved=0ahUKEwjzqv3_t4CCAxVaV6QEHY8BCjwQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=tn+true+neutral&gs_lp=Egdnd3Mtd2l6Ig90biB0cnVlIG5ldXRyYWwyBRAhGKABSKlEUIkIWP1BcAJ4AJABAJgBVqABwQiqAQIxNrgBA8gBAPgBAagCAMICBRAAGIAEwgILEC4YgAQYxwEY0QPCAgUQLhiABMICCxAuGIAEGMcBGK8BwgIHEAAYgAQYCsICBhAAGBYYHsICCBAAGBYYHhgKwgIIEAAYigUYhgPCAgcQABgNGIAEwgIGEAAYHhgNwgIIEAAYBRgeGA3CAggQABgIGB4YDcICBxAhGKABGAo&sclient=gws-wiz#ip=1)